# Python/Mysql UTF8/UTF8MB4 configuration problem?

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

Since last release of Wordpress I get a

> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (3719, "'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release error in out logfiles. How to fix that?

Comment: simply don-'t use utf8 or ignore the warning

Answer (score 0):

That is an annoying warning.  You can *probably* ignore it.

- The `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` columns in your WP tables (and zillions of other tables around the globe) were declared `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  This was reasonable when the tables were first created.
- `CHARACTER SET utf8mb3` does not handle all Chinese characters or Emoji; `utf8mb4` does.
- The warning message hints at how MySQL is transitioning from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4.  But it does not say when or in what way the switchover will happen.
- "How to fix"?  I hesitate to say.  There are multiple ways, none is simple.  I do think it is safe to ignore the message for now.
- The goal is for `utf8` to refer to the better `utf8mb4`, but it will be clumsy to get there.

Keep your eye on bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106389